# difficulty in query building

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, eloquent

i want to show all of the job posts of a company. i have defined the relationship models.

```
    class Company extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'name',
        'company_size',
        'slogan',
        'website',
        'logo',
        'message_title',
        'message_content',
        'main_photo',
        'about_us',
        'why_us',
        'recruiting_steps',
        'address',
        'email',
        'phone_number',
        'location',
    ];
    public function Users(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User');
    }
    public function job_posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\JobPost', 'company_id');
    }
}
```

job posts model:

```
    class JobPost extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'job_posts';

    protected $fillable = [
        'company_id',
        'user_id',
        'title',
        'summary',
        'description',
        'requirements',
        'benefits',
        'approval',
        'location',
        'publish_date',
        'expiration_date'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Company', 'company_id');
    }
    public function cv_folders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CvFolder');
    }

}
```

my companies controller show method

```
 public function show(Company $company)
    {
        //
        $company = Company::find($company->id);
        $JobPosts = $company->JobPosts;
        return view('Companies.show', [
            'company' => $company,
            'JobPosts' => $JobPosts,

        ]);
    }
```

my companies view:

```
@foreach($JobPosts as $jobPost)
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="box box-default box-solid">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h3 class="box-title">{{$jobPost->title}}</h3>
                    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i
                                    class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-tools -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-body" style="">
                    The body of the box
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

but i get the error

"Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\hrlead\resources\views\companies\show.blade.php)"
please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your method:

```
public function job_posts(){
```

to:

```
public function jobPosts(){
```

and rename

```
$JobPosts = $company->JobPosts;
```

to:

```
$JobPosts = $company->jobPosts;
```

After this it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong variable.

it should be `$company->job_posts` rather than `$company->JobPosts`. PHP is a bit case sensitive in variables and functions.